# Soldering tip is made of copper enclosed in other metals

Tags: heat, tools

Why is a soldering tip made of copper enclosed in other metals?

Why is it not just simply solid copper?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Copper is used for the core of the iron tip because it's an excellent conductor of heat, so does a good job transferring energy from the heating element to the tip.

However copper is also affected by solder/tin/flux. If you apply solder to a pure copper tip and keep heating it, the copper will be eaten away by the solder and acidic flux (it literally disolves) - you end up with lots of small pits in the tip which keep growing until it becomes useless.

By coating the copper in a thin layer of more resistant metals such as iron, you prevent the solder from eating away at the copper core, increasing the lifetime of the tip whilst maintaining the good thermal conductivity of the core.

Comment: Not just "essentially" dissolves, it literally dissolves. Copper is very soluble in tin. Lead-free solder alloys often contain additives (often nickel, or a controlled amount of copper to begin with) specifically to reduce the solubility of copper.

Comment: @Hearth I was going to go with literally originally, but not being a chemist, I chickened out.

Comment: I have used solid copper for soldering. What would happen is the point would become duller and duller (like a pencil) until eventually, there was essentially no point at all, just a rounded end of the copper.

Answer (score 2):

Copper corrodes/oxidizes almost immediately when heated. It is coated with more stable metals so that the tip lasts a long time and you don't have to change them out every few minutes.

Comment: Copper tips should be immediately tinned with solder upon heating. This protects them from corrosion and oxidation. However, the copper will eventually dissolve in the solder, with the tip point becoming ever more "dull" and rounded.

Answer (score 1):

I still have old copper soldering irons which are basically a block of copper 1" square and 3" long formed to a point at one end on a handle.

These have been used to solder terminals to large copper cables (like the cables to starter motors on cars) and have lasted for years.

Kept clean, not overheated and used with flux they still work well. I don't find a massive rate of acidic corrosion as suggested in the other answers.

Answer (score -1):

Cu alone makes for a good soldering tip. The addition of Fe makes it semi-crap because at temperature, the tip oxidizes really fast and then it won’t wet with solder. Cu will not last forever but it won’t dissolve before your eyes, either.

Comment: Copper will actually "dissolve before your eyes."  I used to have an old, cheap soldering iron for which I could not buy new tips.  I made them myself out of heavy copper wire.  You could see pits forming it the tip while using it.  After a few hours, I'd have to take the tip out and hammer and file it back into shape.  Good tips for good irons last months if not years.

Comment: I have used pure copper soldering tips. No, the tip won't dissolve immediately, but the tip will need to be replaced after a day of continuous use. Copper wire tips can be re-pointed with a lathe if one is available.